# Critic Badge not activated

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I know that I've down-voted, but the Critic badge has not been applied. I don't know if this is a bug or there is a purposeful delay.

Answer (score 9):

D'oh, my bad. Forgot to flip a setting when launching the site earlier today.

That's fixed now and the badge awards should catch up shortly. Sorry about that!

Comment: Can confirm that badges are working well now. Thanks for the quick fix :)

Comment: @Adam are you the developer behind the site?

Comment: @MarkYisri One of them, yes.